# How do I perform VS 2010 cross domain remote debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cross-domain, remote-debugging

Can someone please point me to some "for dummies" step-by-step guide for remote debugging using Visual Studio 2010?

I need remote debug a web service. My computer and the server are in different domains.

I've been reading [this in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) for two days and still have no clue.

Best regards, Primoz

---

I get this error:

> Unable to connect to the Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor
>   named 'remote.host'.   The Visual
>   Studio Remote Debugger on the target
>   computer cannot connect back to this
>   computer.  A firewall may be
>   preventing communication via DCOM to
>   the local computer. Please see Help
>   for assistance.

I'm using win 7 and on remote server is win 2008 r2. I turned off firewall on both ends.

Comment: what issues have you been running into?  the link you provided is pretty complete.  Does it not connect?  Can you attach to the remote process?  Do the symbols not load?

Comment: I added the error I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that Remote debugging on a server that's in a different domain requires you to add your domain account to the administrators group and to the Permissions section of the remote debugger.

Comment: I can't do this. I see both domain controlesrs but I can't see any users on DC where I am.

Comment: And how would you go about doing that if its not a trusted domain?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your win7 machine is not behind another firewall, such as ones found in home routers and corporate networks. You might need to add rules to these firewalls to allow the connection to go through. You might also need additional configuration if your home router uses NAT (the server sees the router's IP and sends the packets there, the router needs to be configured about where it should forward these packets).

If all else fails try traceroute from the server to your development machine, this might give you a clue as to what's stopping the packets from flowing in. (I am assuming a network problem, not a login issue).

Answer (score 0):

For across domain debugging also need to edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file on local computer.

Just add remote computer's ip address like this:

```
172.172.172.172     SRV-TEST-ADRESS
```

Where:

- `172.172.172.172` - ip address of your remote server
- `SRV-TEST-ADRESS` - Server's name from Visual Studio Remote Debugger
  Monitor on remote computer

You can know your server's ip address by `ipconfig` in `cmd`

[image: Visual Studio Remote Debugger Monitor]

If you need more details explanation, check this [link](http://www.ichi.co.uk/post/21454441582/cross-domain-visual-studio-2010-remote-debugging).